# How do I make a .toLowerCase work in this particular case.. Seems not to work at all

Tags: java, case-sensitive

So i've always been having problems with .toLowerCase and I've checked loads of articles, Videos and books on how it works. I tried making a silly game as a joke for my friends and obviously this wont work

What's the best way to fix it and how do i .toLowerCase() work? If a simple explanation could be given i'd be very happy!!
:)

the "Choice " is a static String.

```
public static void part1()
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Chapter ONE ");
            System.out.println("This is just a simple Left Right options.");
            System.out.println("-------------------------");
            System.out.println("You emerge into a cave like structure, It's seems very weird and creeps you out a little, Yet, You continue on your journey \n You see a that you have reached a 'Dead End' and \n now you have two choices: Either go Left into the weird corner, Or Go Right.. Into the Well-Lit Area.");
            choice = input.next();
            if(choice.toLowerCase()=="left")
            {
                deathPre();
            }
            else if(choice.toLowerCase()=="right")
                {
                    TrFight();
                }
            }
```

So this is the part where it doesnt work (Yeah, It's the first part ironically)i've tried other ways to make this work. Though this being the simplest for me to do suddenly became impossible.

Please help!

Logic : If the user inputs "Left" (doesnt matter which case because i convert it to lower case either way).. It should send the user to "deathPre();
And if he inputs "right" it should go to "TrFight();
Anything else causes an error which i dont mind. But i need the "Left" and "Right" to work

Comment: String comparisons need to be done with .equals(), not ==

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you compare strings with `.equals()` you could also use

```
.equalsIgnoreCase("left")
```

If you use the second one you don't need to use '.toLowerCase()'

Edit:

Like Erik said you could also use

```
.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("left")
```

Comment: I would also use '.trim()' to remove spaces at the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Like Zim-Zam already commented, you need to compare the strings using `equals`, not the `==` operator:

```
if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("right"))
...
else if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("left"))
```

`.toLowerCase()` is probably doing its job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this instead:

```
public static void part1()
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Chapter ONE ");
        System.out.println("This is just a simple Left Right options.");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println("You emerge into a cave like structure, It's seems very weird and creeps you out a little, Yet, You continue on your journey \n You see a that you have reached a 'Dead End' and \n now you have two choices: Either go Left into the weird corner, Or Go Right.. Into the Well-Lit Area.");
        choice = input.next();
        if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("left"))
        {
            deathPre();
        }
        else if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("right"))
            {
                TrFight();
            }
```

To compare two strings, use the equals method in String object.